# How can I add an event listener to a sprite on THREE js?

Tags: events, three.js

I have several markers on a 3d globe in THREE JS. I tried this

```
function onDocumentMouseDown( event ) {

  event.preventDefault();

  mouse.x = ( event.clientX / renderer.domElement.clientWidth ) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / renderer.domElement.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

  raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );

  var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( objects );

  console.log('outside');

  if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {

    console.log('inside');

      intersects[0].object.callback();

  }

}

document.addEventListener( 'click', onDocumentMouseDown, false );
```

But it always prints 'outside'. Should I add the event to the sprite itself? or to the parent mesh? Thanks.

FYI, the `callback` comes from `marker.callback = function() { console.log( 'HERE !!!' ); }`

Comment: I'm actually quite interested in this question, I'm deliberately gonna keep an eye on this, while I'm becoming intermediate with plain/vanilla JavaScript, I've not yet looked at three js, personally. But it's been something I've been thinking on learning for quite some time.

Comment: I've been struggling for days in this..and none of the stackoverflow answer helped me...

Comment: Hmm.... I personally wouldn't know where to start, but I look forward to see if someone answers, because it sure as hell would be useful for me too, when I finally start learning three js.

Comment: https://github.com/stemkoski/stemkoski.github.com/tree/master/Three.js . This has a lot of cool examples but it didn't help me either. Also, a lot of THREE JS resources out there are from different versions....and every f*cking version has breaking changes.

Comment: Oh wait, I think I can see a minor bug with your code already... With the call back, I think you have to have it inside a function... I *think*, I know it can eb a bit buggy if you only provide the callback function name... I.e. try `'click', function(){onDocumentMouseDown(); }, false);`... I think that's actually just a js thing? ... Take a look at [this post I just wrote](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/187866/cleanest-way-to-implement-two-way-data-binding)

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V Providing a function name to `addEventListener` is completely valid, and I have _never_ seen it be even "a bit buggy." **João Vilaça**: Are you saying it prints "outside" but not "inside"? That would mean you did not intersect anything. Is your canvas full-page? If not, `clientX/Y` might not work. Try [`layerX/Y`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/UIEvent/layerX) instead. The docs say it's non-standard, but all major modern browsers support it.

Comment: @TheJim01 I was just taking a shot in the dark, and I can't remember where I've seen that bug occur, I think it with cross compatibility and with some out of date/not commonly used browser....

Comment: Im close to getting it to work. Will post the solution or the closest to it in few moments.

Comment: @JoãoVilaça Nice one!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15658704/intersect-sprites-with-raycaster has the answer.

Comment: Is this question about event listeners or intersecting THREE.Sprite objects?!?

Comment: a little bit of both actually